# convert a method to work with gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, methods

I've got a huge method that prints multiple lines, numbers, characters and uses system.out and multiple data types, it works. But I'd like to use it in a jframe. I tried converting every system.out statement to a jtextArea.setText(), and did casting for non string types but nothing comes out when I run it.

Is it possible? what is the right way of doing that.
jtextarea right for my method.

Comment: If you want to append to a `JTextArea`, consider using it's `append` method. WIthout code it is hard to tell what the issue is

Comment: ^ code, printRep is my JTextArea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to append text to a `JTextArea`, use the `append` method. Right now your code is using `setText`, which does just that: sets the text of the JTextArea, *removing all previous text* in the process (and in this way your code seems to almost guarantee that the JTextArea either contain no text, or contain a single new line character).

Comment: worked in a a weird way, thanks! edges of the tree are printed correctly in my jfame, but with the values "nodes" are displayed in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

try jTextField if its only gonna output.
Try jTextField.append if the user will write stuff on the text.

Comment: jTextField, for output okay. but what method should i use ?